# Is there a common file format and tools for those cheap 60-in-1 NES emulators?

Tags: emulation, nes

A few months back I purchased one of those [cheap 60-in-1 NES emulators](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B09MHW86LW) that output to HDMI for the purpose of my car’s rear entertainment system (GameGnu I think the brand is). I realized the other day that there is a small 128MB microSD card that pops out; I figure that I might be able to take advantage of this to load other games on it.

Unfortunately, it isn’t simply an XML/CSV/JSON file to describe with .CRT/ROM files to go along with it. Actually, looking in the .bin files I do see, they even have Photoshop / Adobe CS XML signatures in it (???).  But menu files seem to be .OCV and .LOG files, and game files seem to be a combination of .BIN and .ASD files.

Does this format sound familiar to anyone? More specifically, are there tools to change out what the games are? It would be cool to add more to this device especially since the 128MB card is only half full.

Comment: I'm curious - what were the actual file extensions of the "Photoshop / Adobe CS XML" files? But asking for any kind of tools/software is a recommendation, which isn't on topic.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't own your emulator, but this .net one probably uses the same format: https://github.com/Art-Stea1th/ASD.NES

Comment: Google also tells me there are several sites that offer compatible rom files. As I assume copyright still applies I'll leave it to you to find these :)